# How to make a program that gives a date 45 days past

Tags: c++, calendar

I want to make a small program that when given a date, will return the date (month and day) 45 days prior to the date given. I have absolutely no clue where to start. I dont want code given to me, just a push in the right direction?

My experience level with programming is making a batch script that remembers your name and tells you hello.

Comment: start with "hello world"

Comment: I think Im just one tiny step past that.

Comment: What thoughts do you have to solve your problem? what observations can you make about dates?

Comment: If that really is your experience level with programming, I think the only reasonable answer anyone can give you is "spend some time learning to program, first, and then try".

Comment: well I know that the days per month alternate between 30 and 31. with the one exception of Feb. which has 28 - 29. So I was thinking of assigning each month a numerical value 0 - 11? then idk. Maybe assgn each month the value of its specific # of days then have it cycle through with simple subtraction after it hits 0 it'll move to the next month? but how could I account for leap years?

Answer (score 4):

With the new [date and time functionality in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) it's incredibly easy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto then = now - std::chrono::hours(24 * 45);

    auto then_c = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(then);

    std::cout << "45 days ago, the time was "
          << std::put_time(std::localtime(&then_c), "%F %T") << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I didnt even know about <chrono>!? I feel like Im always making things more difficult than they are

Comment: @Dlorwisdom Well it's kind of new, and not all compilers/libraries implement it fully. The `std::put_time` function, for example, might not be implemented everywhere, but then you can add an intermediate step using [`std::strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) instead.